# Significance of Equal Angle Triangle Center

Tags: geometry, triangles, triangle-centres

While playing around with triangle centers and came across one I did not know, the center where each triangle corner heading is equally spaced ($120^\circ$ spacing).

[image: Equal Corner Heading Triangle Centers]

Does this specific triangle center have a name, and does it have any significance?

Comment: Probably it is the Fermat point http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatPoints.html

Comment: Perhaps explore the [Encylopedia of triangle centers](http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html).

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "triangle corner heading", but if you mean the angles at the orange point in your figures are equal, then that centre does not always exist for all triangles. Indeed, it only exists if your triangle is equilateral.

Comment: Thank you all! Looks to be the Fermat point.

Comment: @Allawonder So all the triangles in the figure are equilateral?

Comment: @Théophile I wasn't referring to any figure. I was reasoning.

Comment: @Allawonder You referred specifically to the "orange point in [OP's] figures", then claimed that these orange points only exist for equilateral triangles.

Comment: @Théophile No. I said **if** he meant the angles at the orange point are *equal,* then etc. So while I mention the figure, I do not refer to it. I do so because there was no other way to talk about the previously mysterious centre. If you can't name it, then you can't talk about it.

Comment: @Allawonder Well, if we want to split hairs, you weren't reasoning, you were making an unsubstantiated claim. The point can clearly exist even if the triangle is not equilateral, as can be seen in the various examples in the figure that you mentioned.

Comment: @Théophile Well done. You completely ignored my immediately previous comment. That's telling.

Comment: @Allawonder I don't think this discussion is going in a fruitful direction, since you seem to be more interested in giving attitude than talking about the actual problem. Perhaps I misunderstood your original comment, but it seems to me that you're claiming that the Fermat point only exists for equilateral triangles (which is obviously false). You haven't actually given any reasoning whatsoever, so it's hard to understand what you're talking about. I'd be interested in hearing your line of thinking, but let's not waste each other's time with insults.

Answer (score 2):

This is the first isogonic centre (Kimberling $X_{13}$), which in a triangle whose angles are all less than $120^\circ$ is also the *Fermat point*, i.e. minimises the sum of distances to the three vertices or solves the Steiner problem for the triangle.

For a triangle with an angle at least $120^\circ$, the Fermat point is exactly on the corresponding vertex.